# How to get store credit in magento 2 EE?

Tags: magento2.3, magento-enterprise

I want to get customer balance(store credit) by customer id in custom collection.

I am loading credit memo collection, so i want to show remaining customer balance with that.

Comment: You need it in phtml or root script??

Comment: I am trying with root script, after that i will convert as phtml.

Comment: okay............

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Below is the code which useful to get store credit..

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap     = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$instance      = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$state         = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$balanceCollection = $objectManager->get('Magento\CustomerBalance\Model\BalanceFactory');
$model = $balanceCollection->create();
$model->setCustomerId(1)->loadByCustomer(); // put your customer id here
echo $model->getAmount();
?>
```

Comment: let me try and check it...

Comment: Sure...........

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine for me.